# Output a 24 by 24 Leech lattice

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation

Input a rank-8 $E_8$ lattice,
$$
M_{E_8}=\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 & -1  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  0 &  -1 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix},
$$

**Question**: how do we output the explicit rank-24 **Leech lattice** by Mathematica? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeechLattice.html that has integer entries (0 or $\pm 1, \pm  2$, etc.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: People who understand *Mathematica* do not necessarily understand the relationship between these two lattices. That’s mathematics, not coding. Do you have a reference explaining the Turyn construction in detail?

Comment: See the section on constructions from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice . I'm a bit confused why you have input. Isn't there just one (The) Leech Lattice generator matrix ?

Comment: @all, I have an input because the input E8 matrix may decide the normalization (integer instead of 1/2 integer) we have for the output Leech lattice normalization (integer instead of 1/2 integer).

Comment: The [Leech generator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice#Constructions) can be obtained by evaluating `Sqrt[8] LatticeData["Leech"] // Normal`  You made need to click on the Show button to see the generator matrix in the Wikipedia article.